# Convert from iso-2022-jp to UTF in ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, imap

I am getting a string from our mail server in iso-2022-jp, and I am having trouble converting it to UTF.

```
sub #=> "=?iso-2022-jp?Q?Auto-Asia-JP-1=1B$B$N$4M=3DLsFbMF$N3NG'=1B(B?="
sub.encoding  #=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

I have tried using Encoding::Converter.

```
ec = Encoding::Converter.new("ISO-2022-JP", "UTF-8")
ec.convert(sub)    #=> "=?iso-2022-jp?Q?Auto-Asia-JP-1=1B$B$N$4M=3DLsFbMF$N3NG'=1B(B?="
```

I have also tried leaving off the first part of the string, the last part of the string, and every combination in between. Ruby thinks that sub is ASCII, but if I try to tell it that it is ISO-2022-JP by using force_encoding then it spits out garbage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string is ascii: non ascii headers are encoded in ascii before being sent so that they can safely pass through mail servers that only understand ascii. The Q indicates that the iso-2022 bytes are encoded using quoted printable.

The bytes to decode are

```
Auto-Asia-JP-1=1B$B$N$4M=3DLsFbMF$N3NG'=1B(B
```

Ruby can decode quoted printable via `.unpack("M").first.gsub('_',' ')` which yields

```
Auto-Asia-JP-1\e$B$N$4M=LsFbMF$N3NG'\e(B
```

If you then do `force_encoding('ISO-2022-JP').encode('UTF-8')` on that string I then get

```
Auto-Asia-JP-1のご予約内容の確認
```

although I don't speak japanese so that may well be nonsense.

You might want to investigate using something like the mail gem which knows all about the intricacies of mail headers.

Comment: The final Japanese means "confirmation of your booking on Auto-Asia-JP-1" so it seems properly decoded. The questioner was confused with character encoding and mail-header encoding.